# Why is my text not showing in Pygame window?

Tags: python, pygame

this is my first time trying to code in general so I brought upon myself to learn how to make a pygame.
I decided to go for a simple cookie clicker
I couldn't get the text to render with the cookie counted value can someone please help me?
[The zip with image and font file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tlboMV29KK49MDn0zX8uk_cH7fN83pkk/view?usp=sharing)

```
# 1 - Import packages
import pygame
# 2 - Define constants
width=700
height=700
FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 30
x = 20; # x coordnate of image
y = 30; # y coordinate of image
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
score = 0
X = 400 #x coord for text
Y = 400 # coord for text
# 3 - Initialize the world
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (width, height ) )
screen.fill(WHITE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Cookie Clicker simplified')
cookie = pygame.image.load("CookieBig.png")
# 4 - Load assets: image(s), sounds,  etc.
cookie = pygame.image.load("CookieBig.png")
screen.blit(cookie ,  ( x,y)) # paint to screen
pygame.display.flip() # paint screen one time
# 5 - Initialize variables

# Text Display
font = pygame.font.Font('arial.ttf', 32) 
text = font.render('COOKIES : ', True, BLACK, WHITE) 
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (X // 2, Y // 2)   


# 6 - Loop forever
running = True
while (running):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            if cookie.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                score += 1
                print("Cookie:",score)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. You have to `blit` the `text` Surface on the Surface which is associated to the window, in the main application loop.

```py
screen.blit(text, textRect)
```

Recreate the text surface, when the score changes

```py
text = font.render('COOKIES : ' + str(score), True, BLACK, WHITE)
```

A `pygame.Surface` object has not position. Thus the position which is returned by [`.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) is (0, 0). Set the position by a keyword argument, when you retrieve the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) from the Surface:

```py
cookie_pos = (x, y)
x, y = event.pos
if cookie.get_rect(topleft = cookie_pos).collidepoint(x, y):
    # [...]
```

I recommend to clear the display, draw the text and update the display in the main application loop rather than the event loop:

```py
cookie_pos = (x, y)

# 6 - Loop forever
running = True
while running:

    # handle the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False   
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            if cookie.get_rect(topleft = cookie_pos).collidepoint(x, y):
                score += 1
                text = font.render('COOKIES : ' + str(score), True, BLACK, WHITE) 

    # <--|

    # clear display
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # draw scene
    screen.blit(cookie, cookie_pos)
    screen.blit(text, textRect)

    # update display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Note, the main application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I notice that the cookie started running everywhere when I click on it, it still register a count but I couldn't find where in the code  that would make the cookie run around. I need it to stay in one place so I could implement ant enemies that would attack the cookie.

Comment: @KaizIsCoding I've changed the example in the answer. Now the  cookie stays in one place.

Comment: @KaizIsCoding Then you did something wrong. How many `pygame.display.flip()` / `pygame.display.update() ` do you have in your code. There has to be 1 at the end of the application loop. If you've more than 1 you'll get flickering.

Comment: Oh I had multiple of them. I removed them and it fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your not putting it on the screen. Like the cookie image, you need to do `screen.blit(text,textRect)`. I would also recommend putting them in the loop so it gets put on the screen every frame. This means if you change x or y, it will move. So something like this

```
running = True
while (running):
    screen.fill(WHITE) #reset the screen
    screen.blit(cookie ,  ( x,y)) # paint to screen
    text = font.render('COOKIES : ', True, BLACK) 
    screen.blit(text,textRect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            if cookie.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                score += 1
                print("Cookie:",score)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It has the same problem with the reply below where the cookie just started to run everywhere...